# Region dropdown based on country dropdown at the product detailed page

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, product-attribute

Hi i want to display  state drop down based on country select in magento product from in admin can any one please given an idea how to do this. i have googled it but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry that this is not a complete answer**

To get all regions attached to a country you can use the `Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection`. This has a function `addCountryFilter` which will limit the regions return to only those that are linked to a given country.

```
Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()
    ->addCountryFilter($countryId)
    ->load();
```

Then using this what you could do is create a select drop down based on the attribute value for the given product.

Comment: David, it looks it's not an answer at all, I think he is looking on how to add product attribute containing countries/regions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what exactly do you want to do is somewhat vague. If you want to add those fields (country and state) to the config, then all you need to do is is add following xml elements to your extension `system.xml` file fields block:

```
<country_id translate="label">
    <label>Country</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <frontend_class>countries</frontend_class>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</country_id>
<region_id translate="label">
    <label>Region/State</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</region_id>
```